# How to write shell script to start some programs?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm making a shell script that will start bunch on programs that l mostly use. I wants commands for them the programs are-
1. skype
2. sublime-text
3. google-chrome
4. Beyond-comopare
5. scudCloud
6. Lampp

i've found some of them-

```
#! /bin/sh
sudo service mysql stop
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
sudo /usr/bin/skype start
sudo /usr/bin/subl start
sudo google-chrome
```

I know the application can be set from startup application also but i need to run some command also.

After running command bash  shell script will run.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I start applications automatically on login?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login)

Comment: @Serg No actually i need to run some command also like this 'service mysql stop' i can't set that things by startup application.

Comment: It is a bit unclear: *when* you want to start these applications (log in?) and why are you using `sudo`? Also: what should we think of when you say: *but i need to run some command also*?

Comment: @JacobVlijm want them when ever i run the bash file, not automatically.

Comment: So you also created the solution, didn't you? Or what doesnt work?

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 yes sort of i want commands to run beyond compare and scudcloud

Comment: You surely want all those application to start with root privileges ?

Comment: @ErrHunter no chrome, sublime and skype can be skip.

Comment: Why are you using `sudo` here? Only `mysql` and `lampp` need it. Also, you don't want `/usr/bin/skype start`, just `/usr/bin/skype`. Same for `subl`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your script with further two entries:

```
$ cat launchscript.sh
#! /bin/sh
sudo service mysql stop
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
sudo /usr/bin/skype start
sudo /usr/bin/subl start
sudo google-chrome
sudo scudcloud 
sudo bcompare
```

Make it executable:

```
sudo chmod +x launchscript.sh
```

Run it:

```
./launchscript.sh
```

Comment: If `$ scudcloud` or `$ bcompare` doesn't work, you have installed/configured the programs wrongly.

Comment: This are not proper commands to start those application, `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start` `sudo /usr/bin/skype start` `sudo /usr/bin/subl start`.

Comment: @ErrHunter I do not know anything of his configurations and so i just added the two cmds for the missing programs, seemed to work however

Comment: You can even use this to open the exact same files, i.e.:
`xdg-open /path/to/your/file`
Also remember that some programs enable you to save your session/project which you can load later.

Answer (score 0):

Put the script to run all the services inside `init.d` directory to make them run at startup.

Comment: i don't want them to run on startup i want to create a .sh file so that when ever  i run that file the programs and command runs, i have found commands for some of them and i want commands for beyond-compare and scudcloud

Comment: Your question is unclear. if you want to run the services when you are running the script, then the script you have written will work.

Comment: after running command bash <my shell script name> shell script will run.